# Actualizar campos con multiples valores provenientes de distintas tablas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

Tengo 3 tablas:

Product_categories (creada a partir de la importacion de un *.csv*)

```
product_reference | category_id | subcategories

REF.001           | 1           | 1/2
```

Categories (creada a partir de la importacion de un *.csv*)

```
id | name

1  | categoria_ejemplo_1
2  | categoria_ejemplo_2
```

Importer* (creada para almacenar todos los datos que necesito de las tablas anteriores)

```
sku     | category

REF.001 | null
```

¿Cómo podría actualizar **Importer** para que quedase de la siguiente forma?

```
sku     | category

REF.001 | categoria_ejemplo_1>categoria_ejemplo_2
```

*Los datos de la tabla **Importer** serian para exportar en *.csv* y poder importarlos a WooComerce, de ahí que necesite importar las categorías de la forma mencionada. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-column-header-reference/#section-4

Comment: No sé bien lo que pretendes, pero de entrada te digo que no me parece una buena idea. Tu tercera tabla debería más bien manejar una asociación de referencias de productos y categorías a través del id de la categoría y la referencia (¿o el id del producto?).

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿en `Product_categories` tienes otra fila así: `REF.001           | 2 ...`? Es que hasta parece que la tabla `Importer` no es necesaria, porque en ella da la impresión de que quieres unir lo que ya tienes en `Product_categories`. O sea, esto: `categoria_ejemplo_1>categoria_ejemplo_2` podrías obtenerlo a través de una consulta, con un simple `GROUP_CONCAT` sin tener que crear otra tabla.

Comment: Necesitaría guardar así las categorías de los productos ya que los datos de la tabla Importer serian para importarlos a WooComerce, el cual solo te deja importar productos y la única manera de importarlos con sus categorías seria de esta forma .

Comment: No sé cómo funciona `WooComerce`... ¿te refieres a que no te permite importar datos si no son tablas? ¿no permite importar archivos `.csv`, datos separados por coma, archivos json, archivos xml, etc? Dudo que una plataforma seria te obligue a tener que crear una tabla para importar datos.

Comment: Si, en .csv. El caso que el importador de woocomerce no te deja importar los productos por un lado y categorias por otro, si no que tendrias que hacerlo de la manera que ya te he comentado.

Comment: Como te decía, si ya tienes los datos en la tabla `Product_categories`, puedes hacer una consulta que te organice los datos como quieres importarlos, los pones en un `.csv` y se lo mandas a `WooComerce`. No veo por qué tener que crear una tabla para eso... ¡crear una tabla con datos de los que ya dispones es una muy mala práctica!.

Comment: Creo que no nos estamos entendiendo. Las tablas que arriba muestro han sido creadas (una por cada .csv que me ha proporcianado) para hacer la importación a WooComerce. Ahora, como resultado, unicamente necesito un csv que contenga todos los datos de productos.

Comment: Ya pero lo que te quiero decir es que tú puedes generar un `.csv` por medio de una consulta, obteniendo los datos directamente de las tablas sin tener que crear una nueva tabla. O sea, puedes hacer una consulta que combine los datos de todas las tablas que quieras mediante `JOIN`, crear el `.csv` a partir de esos resultados e importarlos a `WooComerce`.

Comment: Realmente seria lo mismo que crear una tabla con los datos necesarios y exportar a .csv, no?

Comment: No... hacer eso sería totalmente contradictorio, sería negar la razón de ser de las bases de datos, sería recargar tu sistema, sería hacer tu sistema difícil de mantener, sería duplicar el trabajo, sería exponerte a datos erróneos o incoherentes. Para poner un ejemplo simple, ya tú tienes la categoría que se llama `categoria_ejemplo_1` en la tabla `Categories`. **Ese dato no debe existir en ninguna otra parte de tu base de datos**, solamente ahí. Si lo necesitas, lo llamas por su id. Eso impide que tengas datos redundantes y si hay que corregir algo, lo corriges solo ahí.

Comment: Creo que seguimos sin entendernos :( Estas tablas han sido creadas únicamente para meter datos en Importer, la cual se exportara en .csv. Ninguna de ellas tienen ninguna funcionalidad, no se relentizaria nada, no hay que mantener nada, no hay que corregir nada. Solo he preguntado si seria posible hacer una consulta para que el resultado sea el que he mostrado. Gracias igualmente por tu tiempo.

Comment: Sí, parece que no será posible que nos entendamos. Tu comentas que *Estas tablas han sido creadas únicamente para meter datos en Importer, la cual se exportara en .csv* y lo que yo te quiero decir es que no necesitas crear una tabla `Importer` para luego a partir de esa tabla exportar los datos a un csv, sino que a partir de las mismas tablas que usas para crear la tabla `Importer` puedes crear el csv y te ahorras el paso de tener que crear una tabla solamente para eso. Es un paso menos que te ahorras y ganas: en rendimiento, en espacio, en rapidez del código, en mantenimiento, en todo...

Comment: ... aunque no lo creas, siempre hay que mantener, siempre hay que optimizar y nunca es lo mismo dar 3 pasos que dar 2, aunque sea ahora un programa sencillo. Las cosas evolucionan y cuando crecen, ese paso, ese dato de más, esa tabla de más... que al principio es uno, se va multiplicando por decenas, por cientos, por miles, por millones. Llega un punto en que todo se ralentiza y no sabes por qué. **¿El problema?** Que pudiendo hacer las cosas en 2 pasos, las hiciste en 3 pasos.

Comment: Efectivamente, no nos entendemos. Un saludo, gracias y buenas tardes.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado:

`UPDATE Importer i
JOIN (
    SELECT pc.product_reference,GROUP_CONCAT(c.name ORDER BY n.n SEPARATOR '>') category
    FROM (SELECT 1 n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) n 
    JOIN Product_categories pc
    JOIN Categories c ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT('',pc.subcategories,'////'),'/',n.n),'/',-1) = c.id
    GROUP BY pc.product_reference
    ) d
SET i.category = d.category
WHERE i.sku = d.product_reference;`